# 2x USB C Thunderbolt ports not being recognized on Lenovo 730S

Tags: lenovo, thunderbolt, usb-c

The device has 3 ports, 1 of which is for charging. Previously I had Win 10 and the  other 2 ports were not being recognized. After some troubleshooting / googling I figured it had to do with the bios and flashed a newer version which solved the problem.

I then burned Ubuntu 18 image on the flash drive and installed it using one of the *other 2 ports*, everything went fine. After the installation, however, these 2 ports just don't work, only the charging port does. Whatever I insert doesn't get mounted. What's even more interesting, I don't see the devices in bios' boot menu either (which I did when installing ubuntu).

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu 18.04.3, I've checked using the 5.0 Linux kernel and there still does not appear to be a driver stack in place for thunderbolt devices. I tested with an external TB3 drive. You can verify that the device is detected by Intel's bus driver by typing boltctl. You can also authorize the device with that utility. If the full stack was in place, it should result in a block device becoming available. The boltctl utility provides a pci sysfs path where you can probe the device for information. That also works fine. Perhaps Linux TB3 peripheral support will be included with USB 4?